# InstallShield for Outlook Add In: INSTALLDIR replaced with wrong path

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield

I have created a outlook addin for outlook 2013. No i need to create a wrapper.

First off if some one has a tutorial it would be great. Next am trying to create a new registry in which the path should be where i install the VSTO file.For this am using the following line in regsitry editor
[TARGETDIR]MyAddIN.vsto|vstolocal
However during install the [TARGETDIR] is replaced with J: which is just another drive. Not sure what am doing wrong please help. Also i have selected Primary Output to be the only thing that needs deploying. Howver am not able to find the VSTO file. Can someone shed some lights on this issue

Answer (score 0):

> First off if some one has a tutorial it would be great.

Here it is: [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> Not sure what am doing wrong please help.

Are you creating Basic MSI type of project? Looks like you are messing with different values "INSTALLDIR" vs. "TARGETDIR". Please read on the difference: [INSTALLDIR vs. TARGETDIR](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield21helplib/helplibrary/FAQFilesInstallDirs.htm). Basically if you would follow the instructions from the tutorial, you should be fine. Take a time and read it through.